# How to get value of <ion-select> no jQuery

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have a user form in which the user gets to choose from three countries and displays it back to the user in the form of an alert. It looks something like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  //alert back to user
  alert(document.getElementById("options").value)
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css" />

</head>

<ion-list>
  <ion-item style="display: none;">
    <ion-label style="display: none;">
      Select Region
    </ion-label>
    <ion-select style="display: none;" id="options">
      <ion-select-option>USA</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option>UK</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option>Canada</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click to retrieve</button>
```

Again, as the title suggests, I do NOT want to use jquery, I only want to use Native, Vanilla JavaScript.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code, having removed the `style="display: none"`, revealing the select.

The code works fine, but the alert shows 'undefined' until you select one of the options.

```js
const opts = document.getElementById("options");

function myFunction() {
  alert('ion-select value: ' + opts.value);
}

// listen for changes to the ion-select
opts.addEventListener('ionChange', function () {
  console.log('ion-select ionChange detected');
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css" />

</head>

<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>
      Select Region
    </ion-label>
    <ion-select id="options">
      <ion-select-option>USA</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option>UK</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option>Canada</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click to retrieve</button>
```

Comment: This is a great answer and I would like to thank you for that. I found a way to hide the element from the user without having to use display: none. I used margin-right: 99999px, and that seemed to work. Although I have marked your answer, would you know how to execute a function when "okay" is pressed when the user selects from the select prompt?

Comment: You want to add an “OK” button that calls a function when clicked?

Comment: Let me re-word that question: how would I run the "myFunction" function when the value of the select changes. For example: when the user changes the value of the ion-select from USA to UK, how would I run the "myFunction" function?

Comment: You would add a listener to the `<ion-select>` element that listens for the 'change' event. See [HTMLElement: change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

Comment: The change function doesn't work in this case. I think that is only for normal select forms. I try to add the attribute: `change = "myFunction()"` to the `<ion-select>` tag and it's not working

Comment: You have to use the ion-specific event names, not the standard 'change' event. See my addition to the code, above, and read the docs: [ion-select events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#events)

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I never knew the ionChange existed, glad you helped!

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you’re doing the right thing but, have you tried to set a value to each option?

Like

```
<ion-select-option value=“USA”>USA</ion-select-option>
```

Comment: Try getting the selected option with : let sel = document.getElementById(“options”); let opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex]; and then try alert(opt.text); or alert(opt.value);

Comment: @robloxGamer3029 It's undefined until you select one of the options. See my answer.

Comment: @terrymorse yes, I see, the display:none styles were the problem